# Java console input in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: java, input, console, sublimetext2

I've recently made the switch to sublime text 2 but I cannot seem to find any plugins/resources which will allow me to implement java console inputs into the editor. I've managed to make it compile and execute java files, but whenever my code needs any input(like a scanner input), the code does not compile and I get an error.

I've seen solutions to make this happen for python, but haven'y managed to find anything on Java.

Comment: For Ubuntu Refer to this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972598/10847305](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972598/10847305)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I've figured out a **complete and perfect** solution to this "Run java in Sublime" problem, I've only tested this in Windows 7.

By following the steps below, you will have 2 Build Systems in sublime - "JavaC" and "JavaC_Input".

- "JavaC" would let you run code that doesn't require user input and display the results in sublime's terminal simulator, which is convenient and nice-looking.
- "JavaC_Input" lets you run code that requires user input in a separate terminal window, it's able to accept user input. You can also run non-input-requiring code in this build system, so if you don't mind the pop-up, you can just stick with this build system and don't switch.

You switch between build systems from Tools -> Build System. And you compile&run code using ctrl+b.

Here are the steps to achieve this:

(note: Make sure you already have the basic setup of the java system: install JDK and set up correct CLASSPATH and PATH, I won't elaborate on this)

**"JavaC" build system setup**

1,  Make a bat file with the following code, and save it under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin\ to keep everything together. Name the file "javacexec.bat".

```
@ECHO OFF
cd %~dp1
javac %~nx1
java %~n1
```

2, Then edit C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Java\JavaC.sublime-build (if there isn't any, create one), the contents will be

```
{
   "cmd": ["javacexec.bat", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java"
}
```

**"JavaC_Input" build system setup (mainly the same as @lac_dev 's answer)**

1, Install Cygwin [http://www.cygwin.com/]

2, Go to C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Java\, then create a file called "JavaC_Input.sublime-build" with the following content

```
{
"cmd": ["javacexec_input.bat", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.java"
}
```

3,  Make a bat file with the following code, and save it under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin\ to keep everything together. Name the file "javacexec_input.bat".

```
@echo off
javac  -Xlint:unchecked %~n1.java 
start cmd /k java -ea %~n1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out on Windows 8, I haven't tested it on any other platform, hope this works for you.

1. Install Cygwin [http://www.cygwin.com/]
2. Make sure the start commands uses the drive:\Path_to_cygwin_installation\bin\start

   - You can verify this with the where command :

     ```
         where start
     ```
3. Create a `javac.sublime.build` system

   - This is mine, it can be improved

   ```
   {
   "cmd": ["javac.bat", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java"
   }
   ```

   - Make sure you update your environment path so it knows where to locate the `javac.bat`; I placed mine under my `java_home` installation.
4. Create your `javac.bat` file and make it available on your environment path

   ```
   @echo off
   javac  -Xlint:unchecked %~n1.java 
   start java -ea %~n1
   ```
5. On my example I had to make sure I kept the application opened:

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   class Test
   {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
           int input = -1;

           while(input != 0)
           {
               System.out.println("=======================");
               System.out.println("What is Your Age? Enter 0 to exit;");
               input = reader.nextInt();
               System.out.println("You've entered " + input + "\n\n");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

You can now compile your java files and get it on a new windows.

Comment: Step 4 can be modified to leave the terminal open as follows :

start cmd /k java -ea %~n1

Comment: Use the following so the new windows stays open:
start cmd /k java -ea %~n1

Comment: "Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld". Any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there are **no solutions** available for Sublime Text 2 or 3.

But I still love it! So what I usually do is just manually specify the input:

```
System.out.print("Enter Stack size: ");
//int input = br.readLine();
int input = 10;
```

leaving the necessary parts commented for when I need to run the program with input (almost never, in fact).