# Perl with Sublime Text 2: <STDIN> not working

Tags: perl, sublimetext2, stdin

I'm new to Perl and am trying to write a simple program that prompts the user to enter a number. I then want that number to be printed. I think I have the correct code, but when I run the program I'm not able to enter anything. I'm using Sublime Text 2. Am I missing a plugin or something? How do I get this to work? I've only done simple if/else statements prior to this and everything worked. I just can't seem to prompt the user for input.

Here is the code:

```
print ("Please enter a number: \n");
$seq = <STDIN>;
print("Sequence = $seq \n");
```

And here is the output:

Use of uninitialized value $seq in concatenation (.) or string at C:\blah\blah\practice.pl line 3. 
Please enter a number: 
Sequence =
[Finished in 0.4s]

Comment: This seems more of a problem with Sublime console. Can you run your program in shell? (cmd.exe on Windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this - very similar - Python question: " [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input) " - Sublime Text doesn't support STDIN input. Confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289352/java-console-input-in-sublime-text-2) as well.

You can solve this one of 2 ways:

1. Run your program outside of Sublime, in shell. On Windows, simply save your Perl script as `c:\your_directory\your_subdir\your_perl_script.pl` ; open the command interpreter (`"Start"=>"Run"=>"cmd.exe"`) and on `c:\` prompt in the interpreter, run:

   ```
   c:\your_directory\your_subdir\your_perl_script.pl
   ```

   or if you didn't associate `.pl` extension with Perl when you installed Perl,

   ```
   perl c:\your_directory\your_subdir\your_perl_script.pl
   ```
2. Follow the linked SO question's answer and use [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)
3. Use the [Terminal plugin](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal)

Comment: Also, a separate solution for Java, but that doesn't seem portable to other languages at first glance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289352/java-console-input-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: Really wish I could do it in Sublime Text 2, but I got it to work in the command prompt. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add an "<>;" at the last line of your perl code.

And then: tools->build new system->

```
{
    "cmd": ["perl","$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.perl",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "RunInCommand",
            "shell": true,
            "cmd": ["start", "perl","${file_base_name}.pl"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, if you want to run your perl code using a shortcut key, such as "F5",
you can add one: preferences->key buildings-user->

```
[
    {"keys": ["f5"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "RunInCommand"}}
]
```

Enjoy programming.