# run java file with user input in Sublime Text

Tags: java, macos, sublimetext2, javac

I'm trying to run a java file with a users input, but I always get this error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"

before the user can enter something..

I know it's normally not possible to input stuff when compiling and running a java file in Sublime Text, but does somebody knows a workaround?

Now I already have this (JavaC.sublime-build) in my Packages - Java directory from Sublime Text so I can compile and run with cmd B but input something is impossible..

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
    "shell": true,
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

(I'm working on OS X)

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289352/java-console-input-in-sublime-text-2?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I saw it but this does not work on Mac OS X