# Sublime Text2 how to add run java label?

Tags: java, sublimetext2

when I choose c++ in Bulid System , I notice there is "Run" command below.
However, when I choose JavaC in Build System , The "Run" label is missing.
how can I add this label to compile and run java ? 
what's more, among the answers in [Compiling and Running Java Code in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2) , I prefer @vijay's than any other ones, but when I config  the following code as he suggested, It does not work when I type "shift+ctrl+b" to run java program

```
{
"cmd": ["javac", "-Xlint", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.java",

"variants": [

    { "cmd": ["java", "$file_base_name"],
      "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
      "selector": "source.java",
      "name": "Run Java"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 will only offer a `Run` menu item (with shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+B`) if there is a build system variant with the name `Run` (see `name` documentation [here](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#options)). In your build system, change this:

```
"name": "Run Java"
```

to this:

```
"name": "Run"
```

Afterwards, `Ctrl+Shift+B` should execute the `java` command that you're going for.

Any other variants that you add will appear in the Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`) with a name like `Build: Foo` but will not be assigned a keyboard shortcut. The one named `Run` will *always* be mapped to `Ctrl+Shift+B` **no matter what order the variants are in.**