# Compile java with unicode support in Sublime Text 3

Tags: java, unicode, sublimetext3

I have comments in my java file that contain accented letters (my name in the header). When I Build in ST3 I get the error:

```
java:5: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
```

Is there any way to fix this other than removing all non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Use `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...` (or another encoding, like Cp1252). Use the same encoding in SublimeText.

Comment: But can I make it so that when I build from ST3 it will run that command, e.g. when i press command-B?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with sublime-build package. Here is the default for python:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "C:\\python33\\python.exe -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Where I have found it is, inside

```
[the sublime installation dir @progfiles]\Packages\Python.sublime-package
```

which is actually a ZIP file.
Open it with wizip / winrar / 7zip or etc
copy the file content of **"Python.sublime-build"** file. 
Inside the Sublime Text editor, from the menu go to

> Tool > Build System > New Build System

You can do same for Java easily. If cannot, let people here know.

*edit:*
(I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2))
I guess this will work. Go to the menu of Sublime as "Tool > Build System > New Build System". A new file will open, replace the content as:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8", "-Xlint", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "variants": [
        { "cmd": ["javac", "-Xlint", "$file"],
          "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
          "selector": "source.java",
          "name": "Java Lintter"
        },
        { 
          "cmd": ["java", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8", "$file_base_name"],
          "name": "Run Java"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) and [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13237).

Comment: I cannot find this folder. It could be that I'm using Sublime Text 3 on a Mac.

Comment: I noticed it should be under "Packages" directory under App Directory and edit that with more information. You can now try what I have written without finding that anyway.

Comment: Are you using ST3 or ST2 because I don't seem to have the same folder structure as you? My packages folder is almost empty. No python or java folder there. Do I need to install a package for this?

Comment: ST3 as you do. Just forget about the directories. You can do what I tell you without the folder/file thing. Inside the SublimeText3, you will just use the menu. [I have a screenshot for you as in here.](http://imgur.com/QOD3y6f)

Comment: javac: invalid flag: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options