# Where I can find Javac.sublime-build file in Sublime Text 3 ? (Windows)

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I want to run java files on ST3. I have read a good guide for the ST2
[Compiling and Running Java Code in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2)
But in 3d version i cant found this configure file.
Is anybody can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer. Plugins in ST3 can be run directly from the `*.sublime-package` file (which are renamed zip files). You could find the package, extract it, and place the file in the proper location to override. The plugin I posted simplifies the process.

Comment: I manually cloned the repository in the location provided by the manual, but I have no idea what to do next in order to run the java programs. I was able to compile java inside Sublime (don't know how to run it inside sublime ) I am using Sublime text 3, Can you please explain the rest of the process

Comment: @Md Faisal I'm not super familiar with how ST3 actually handles builds.  You may want to try asking on the Sublime text forums https://forum.sublimetext.com

Comment: @ skuroda thank you for suggestion however I finally found out how to run Java inside Sublime and for people like me out there here is the link for the same:-  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXDdhRH7J84