# Is it possible to build/run java with libraries using Sublime Text 2

Tags: java, build, sublimetext2, javac

I am able to build java programs in Sublime Text 2 using the build script. However, is it possible to modify the script to include referenced libraries in the build automatically, say in a folder lib\.

```
{
"cmd": ["javac", "-Xlint", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.java",

"variants": [
    { "cmd": ["java", "$file_base_name"],
      "name": "Run"
    }
]
}
```

Thanks

**Edit:**
I am now able to build and run from Sublime Text using

```
{
"cmd": ["javac", "-cp", "*;.", "-Xlint", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.java",

"variants": [

    { "cmd": ["java", "-cp", "*;.", "$file_base_name"],
      "name": "Run"
    }
] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an external script file (e.g. **java-build**) and reference it from **JavaC.sublime-text**:

```
  "cmd": ["java-build", "$file", "$file_path"],
```

If the **lib** folder is located next to the java file being compiled, the script may look like this:

**java-build.bat** (for Windows):

```
@echo off
cd %2
javac -cp "*;." -Xlint %1 %2\lib\*.java
```

**java-build.sh** (for Unix):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $2
javac -cp ./*:. -Xlint $1 $2/lib/*.java
```

If you want your *.class* files to be put in a separate place add **-d *path*** argument to javac.
It is also a good idea to delete old classes before compiling to make sure you won't use different versions if compiler breaks on some file: `-rm *.class` (`del *.class` for windows).

This discussion may help: [Compiling and Running Java Code in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2)