# Java with Sublime Text - Scanner not working?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, sublimetext

I am trying to learn Java, and I've just started. I want to run this code I found online:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // needed for Scanner

/** A Java program that demonstrates console based input and output. */
public class MyConsoleIO 
{
    // Create a single shared Scanner for keyboard input
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

    // Program execution starts here
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        // Prompt the user
        System.out.print( "Type some data for the program: " );


        // Read a line of text from the user.
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        // Display the input back to the user.
        System.out.println( "input = " + input );

    } // end main method

} // end MyConsoleIO class
```

However I get this error:

```
Type some data for the program:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at MyConsoleIO.main(MyConsoleIO.java:17)
[Finished in 0.9s with exit code 1]
```

I am running the code in Sublime Text 2, directly in the editor, pressing CMD+B.

Comment: Did you try calling `scanner.hasNextLine()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Sublime Text, but your program looks correct. I ran it in my NetBeans 8.0.1 and all works fine. It looks like it is a problem in how Sublime runs java programs.

Try compile and run it with standard java compiler and run tools. For further details read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html

**See also:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810204/1981450

Comment: He could be right, sublime could not allow interaction with System.in.

Comment: I think that's problem in **how** sublime runs java programs. It looks like it somehow skips user input on `nextLine()` and method throws exception, as wrote in sources: `if (result == null) throw new NoSuchElementException("No line found");`

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `nextLine()` directly, you need to check first if a line is available (the user has hit enter) with `scanner.hasNextLine()` that blocks until that line can be read.

```
String input ="";

if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
  input=scanner.nextLine();
}
```

The [javadoc for Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) describes this behaviour, the summary on top usually gives you all the information you need to use that class.

Also, if you are a beginner, the book *Thinking in Java* is usually recommended.

Comment: I added your code int the program (replacing 
String input = scanner.nextLine();
)
However, I got this errormessage:
MyConsoleIO.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
            input=scanner.nextline();
                         ^
  symbol:   method nextline()
  location: variable scanner of type Scanner
1 error
Now when I replaced the lowercase "l" in the row input=scanner.nextline();
so that it became input=scanner.nextLine();, the program just finished without me entering anything:
Type some data for the program: input = 
[Finished in 0.9s]
. So I still can't enter anything.

Comment: That way you will not be able to use `input` outside the if (not a problem), read about *variables scope* to learn more about this if interested.

Comment: Ok, but even if i place the row: System.out.println( "input = " + input ); inside the if-statement I can't enter anything from my keyboard, I get this message: Type some data for the program: [Finished in 0.9s]

Comment: Java is case sensitive, nextline() and nextLine() are two different methods.

Comment: Okay. When I use nextline(), I get the following error message: 
MyConsoleIO.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
            input=scanner.nextline();
                         ^
  symbol:   method nextline()
  location: variable scanner of type Scanner
1 error

Comment: nextline() does not exist :), it's nextLine().

Comment: Other than this, if everything is still like in your question, plus my if, it must work, it prints your "Type some data", waits for some input+ enter key, and prints. If it still doesn't work, try editing your question adding at the end the new code, and i'll take a look at it.

Comment: Wait. I'm not sure that sublime text actually allows you to type something inside the editor... go in that directory and type: `javac MyConsoleIO.java` and then once it has compiled your file run it with `java MyConsoleIO ` (without .java at the end)

Comment: Thank you! 
P.S. I had to use .nestLine() in order for it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String read(String text) {
      System.out.println(text);
      return read();
}

private String read() {
      if (!scan.hasNext())
      System.exit(0);
      return scan.next();
}
```

write and scan with

```
String string = read("Input: ");
```

only read with...

```
String string = read();
```