# Java swing on text editor

Tags: java, swing

How can I set or configure a text editor like sublime text or atom, to work on java proyects. It is for school, i have a restriction where i cannot use an IDE. I will creeate a simple aplication based on java swing. What do you recommend me to do? (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: look into this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use TextArea from java swing tools and menu to do actions like save,edit,delete .. etc