# Is there a way to quickly rebuild and run Java code rather than "javac file.java" and then "java file"?

Tags: java, cmd

I have a very simple java code - I'm just learning Java.

However I don't want to have to retype `javac file.java` and `java file` again and again for a little change.

Is there a way to do it faster? Or a one-liner that I can quickly copy & paste?

Comment: I don’t know Java at all, but couldn’t you just run `javac file.java && java file` as a one liner, then press up in the terminal to get the last entered command and not have to retype it?

Comment: Or put the above into a batch script.

Comment: IDEs will also automatically do stuff like this for you. Learning the low level stuff like this is good, but using good tools will make your life easier.

Comment: Which editor are you using? There may be a convenient way to run the code from the editor.

Comment: Sublime text. It doesn't have a build option for Java. I have VSCode and I don't know if that does it, but @Andy 's solution is what I wanted. If he'll write it up as an answer, I can accept it. Of course, if there's some advantages for Java for coding from VScode, I'll use that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling and Running Java Code in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560295/compiling-and-running-java-code-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run both commands as a one-liner, using `&&` so that the second command will only run if the first was successful:

```
javac file.java && java file
```

Then you can just press up in the terminal window to access the command without having to retype it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IDE, such as Eclipse or NetBeans, to directly run without typing anything. This is because the IDE automatically recompiles changed code for you.

Download link for Eclipse:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/kepler/sr1/eclipse-ide-java-developers

Comment: Well, I don't think its fully feasible to download a whole IDE for this.

Comment: Sure it is feasible.  And you get a lot more benefit than just this.  (Almost nobody does serious Java dev using the command line and a text editor these days.)

Comment: Yeah, I have Visual Stdio but I'm not serious yet.